# Sails auto include assets file issue

Tags: sails.js

I want sails include assets file with sort order. 
Example: I want to include jquery.js first, then bootstrap.js
But sails include with sort abc and it include bootstrap.js first and then jquery.js

Answer (score 0):

in sails js version v0.10.5 just going task/pipeline.js in jsFilesToInject block, put link to jquery file in the first line of this block.
like:

```js
var jsFilesToInject = [

      // Load sails.io before everything else
      'js/dependencies/sails.io.js',

      // will be injected here in no particular order.
      'js/jquery.js',

      // will be injected here in no particular order.
      'js/**/*.js',

      // Dependencies like jQuery, or Angular are brought in here
      'js/dependencies/**/*.js'

      // All of the rest of your client-side js files
    ];
```